# LINQ lambda for many to many relationship

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

There is a many-to-many data relationship between Products and CategoryGroups and I'm selecting all the Products (from a starting point of productList) that are also in specific CategoryGroups (the list of CategoryGroup Ids is given in groupIds).

This can be successfully achieved using the following LINQ expression:

```
productList =
    from p in productList
    where (
    from g in p.CategoryGroup
    where groupIds.Contains(g.CategoryGroupId)
    select g
    ).Any()
    select p;
```

where:

```
var productList = db.Products
    .Where(a => a.ThisCondition == thisCondition)
    .ToList();  

var groupIds = db.CategoryGroups
    .Where(a => a.ThatCondition == thatCondition)
    .Select(a => a.CategoryGroupId)
    .ToList();
```

Is it possible to replace the productList LINQ expression with one LINQ lambda expression ?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have represented your many to many relationship using two collection navigation properties like in this [tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx), you can simplify your queries to this:

```
var productList = db.Products
                    .Where(a => a.ThisCondition == thisCondition 
                                && a.CategoryGroups.Count(c=>groupIds.Contains(c.CategoryGroupId))>0);
```

Or you could also use `Any` extension method:

```
var productList = db.Products
                    .Where(a => a.ThisCondition == thisCondition 
                                && a.CategoryGroups.Any(c=>groupIds.Contains(c.CategoryGroupId)));
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you - both work. Much appreciated.